# Is inlet pipe required for a 95v furnace

Tags: furnace

In mid 2015 we got a [95v American Standard furnace](https://www.americanstandardair.com/products/heating-and-cooling/furnaces/gold-95v-furnace.html). After a year, we got inspection done which was required for warranty. The inspection guy said `No intake pipe is ran at all. Unit must have an intake pipe bringing in air from outside. This is city code`.

I called Integrity, the company that sold/installed this unit, and mentioned this. He said `This particular unit does not require an intake pipe. We can do it, it will cost $500`. I'm finding that shady.

I paid over $7,000 total (with monthly installments) for A/C and furnace and don't think it is fair that they charge me more to make another hole in the basement wall which they could have done when they installed it. They made one hole anyway for vent/outlet.

So, is the inspection guy right or the integrity guy? I tried to find instruction manual for this unit to see if it says anything about inlet pipe being optional but couldn't find it.

I'm a first time home owner - how do I deal with this company, Integrity? Or is he right and I should pay and get it done. Or should I ask them to come fix it and then refuse to pay - will I get in trouble?

Comment: What's the purpose of the inspection? If it's a city building inspector, generally the contractor is responsible for doing work that passes inspection. However, if the work has already passed inspection and this is e.g. a third party home warranty, the inspector could be asking for something that isn't really necessary. Many furnaces do not require an intake connected to outside.

Comment: Oh, I had inspection done by a third party. Integrity had said for the units to stay in warranty, they need to be inspected by someone licensed annually.

Comment: If you can identify the model number of your furnace, you may be able to find info online by searching for "American Standard AUH2B060A9V3VB installation guide". This should tell you if intake air must come only from outside. From what I can tell that might be optional according to the manufacturer. What the city or warranty inspector wants is another question.

Comment: Usually for warranties from the installer, they just want to make sure someone is checking and cleaning the system annually. If the intake does not meet the manufacturer's requirements, that's both a performance/reliability and safety issue. If the intake doesn't meet city requirements, that could be a permitting issue for you. But it's quite possible the intake is OK and your inspector was wrong; read an installation guide and call your city's inspection services department to check.